# How to set/get size of editable area in a neovim client

Tags: neovim

I'm writing a client for Neovim. The rpc api has a `nvim_ui_try_resize({width}, {height})` method to resize the screen of Neovim instance. But I need to set the exact size of the editable area (excluding tabbar header, sign column, numbers column, cmdline, statusbar, etc).

My first question is: is it possible to set the size of the editable area directly?

And as I expect a "No" as the answer to my first question my second question is: is it possible to query the size of the editable area? (so that I can set it by trial and error)

I don't want hacky solutions, I need something that will still work after Neovim upgrades.